# How to send parameter outside of the RSwag schema in the RSpec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rswag

With RSwag and RSpec in Ruby on Rails, is it possible to send a parameter that is not defined as a `parameter` via the `run_test!`?

Example test:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "swagger_helper"

describe "Resources", type: :request, swagger_doc: "api/resources.json" do
  path "/resources" do
    get "get resources" do
      tags "resources"

      parameter name: "sort[column]",
                in: :query,
                type: :string,
                enum: ["created_at", "updated_at"]
                required: false
      parameter name: "sort[order]",
                in: :query,
                type: :string,
                enum: ["asc", "desc"]
                required: false

      response "422", "Unprocessable Entity" do
        context "with unrecognized param" do
          # define sort[direction] here

          run_test! do |respone|
            expect(json_response["errors"]).to contain_exactly(
              # my serialized response error
            )
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to send `sort[direction]` in my `context`. What I have tried so far:

```
let(:"sort[direction]") { "asc" }
let(:sort) { { direction: "asc" } }
let(:sort) { { "direction" => "asc" } }
```

with no avail - I got HTTP 200 Success, even though the same request sent via Postman with `sort[direction]` defined responds with expected HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to do it this way:

```
context "with unrecognized sort param" do
  before do |example|
    example.metadata[:example_group][:operation][:parameters] += [{
      name: "sort[direction]",
      in: :query,
      type: :string,
      required: false
    }]
  end

  let(:"sort[direction]") { "asc" }

  run_test! do |respone|
    expect(json_response["errors"]).to contain_exactly(
    # my serialized response error
    )
  end
end
```

It does not add the params to the generated OpenAPI JSON file, which is good.

Comment: or `parameter name: :'sort[direction]', in: :query, type: :string, required: false`